# run function after toggle doesn't work correctly when reversed

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidetoggle

I'm using the following jquery function to slideToggle .toggle-box and scroll to top after the slideToggle is complete.
This works well when sliding down .toggle-box but when sliding it up both functions seem to run at the same time.
Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7udLq/12/

```
jQuery(".toggle-box").hide();

jQuery("a.toggle").click(function (e) {

    jQuery(".toggle-box").slideToggle(1500, function () {
        jQuery("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery(".toggle").offset().top
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            easing: "easeOutQuint"
        });
    });

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

**UPDATE:**
The fix is actually very easy and works with simple css.
By adding bottom:0; to the box that is toggled it works fine

```
.toggle-box {
    background-color:green;
    height:500px;
    bottom:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7udLq/16/

Comment: I don't see your problem (Chrome 24)

Comment: @sdespont  see it toggles at same time than scrolltop

Comment: So do you want it o scroll while it is animating?

Comment: @chad no, I want jquery to finish the toggle animation first and then do the scrolling. currently this is working fine when sliding down the toggle-box <div>. but when clicking the button again the box slides up and the page scrolls to top at the same time (the scroll function should run after the toggle function is complete though )

Answer (score 0):

Problem is when box `slideup`, body height change and so browser `scroll` to top of page.

See what im talking about here: (im using slideDown/slideUp on demonstration purpose, inserting a temp div when slideDown/scrolltop is completed)

http://jsfiddle.net/7udLq/13/

Comment: thank you @roasted. but am i missing something, the scrollto function doesn't seem to work in your example